# Rails double Many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm stuck with the UI for the following models, I have three models (badges, sprint, user) and I want to award user with badges but make it sprint dependant. So I have the following model

**Badge:**

```
class Badge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sprint_badges
  has_many :sprints, through: :sprint_badges
end
```

**Sprint**

```
class Sprint < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lessons
  has_many :badges, through: :sprint_badges
  has_many :sprint_badges
  belongs_to :group
end
```

**Sprint x Badge**

```
class SprintBadge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sprint
  belongs_to :badge

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**User:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :sprint_badges
end
```

So in my user (_form.html.erb) I want to create something like this

```
Badges   
   sprint1
     checkbox - badge 1
     checkbox - badge 2   
   sprint 2
     checkbox - badge 1
     checkbox - badge 2
```

So I don't know what helper can I use to generate this type of ui form.

Comment: where is your sprint model?

Comment: I added the sprint model